# FullSimplify does not distribute Abs over multiplication

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
FullSimplify[Abs[x]^2, x \[Element] Reals]
```

reasonably returns `x^2`, but the barely-more-complicated expression

```
FullSimplify[Abs[x y]^2, {x, y} \[Element] Reals]
```

returns `Abs[x y]^2` unsimplified.  Any ideas why?  I can just do the replacement rule

```
{Abs[x_]^2 -> x^2}
```

at the end of a complicated expression if I know that `x` is real, but now I'm worried that `FullSimplify[]` is missing other obvious places to remove `Abs[]`.

Comment: FWIW, `FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[Abs[x y]^2], {x, y} ∈ Reals]` does yield `x^2y^2`.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` is another way to get your desired result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`FullSimplify` returns the simpler expression:

```
Simplify`SimplifyCount[Abs[x y]^2]

(* 6 *)

Simplify`SimplifyCount[x^2 y^2]

(* 7 *)
```

See also the documentation for [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html), in particular the Scope section.

Comment: Mathematica considers Abs[x y]^2 to be simpler than (x y)^2, even though the Abs[] requires an extra operation?  Bizarre.  I suppose in the latter case, it first distributes the square and so has to perform two squaring operations, which is more computationally intensive than taking an absolute value and then performing a single squaring operation.

Comment: @tparker  Look at FullForm for each expression.

Comment: @tparker Simplicity is in the eye of the beholder: `FullForm[(x y)^2]` is not simpler than `FullForm[Abs[x y]^2]`. Yes, `(x y)^2` does autoevaluate to `x^2 y^2`. One can always define a custom `ComplexityFunction`.